# KeyboardInterrupt というエラーが出てしまう

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

プログラミング初心者の大学生です。

練習問題として提示された内容についての質問です。

> 【練習問題】
> Step 1:金額の入力(整数:int)
> Step 2:人数の入力(整数:int)

先生が掲載してくださったものをコピーし、colaboratory上にペーストした状態でもエラーが出てしまいます。あまり知識が無いため、どのように対処してよいか分かりません。

お手数をお掛けしますが、解決策をご提示いただければ幸いです。

[image: エラー画面のスクリーンショットです]

Comment: セルを実行した後に何かしましたか？

Comment: エラー部分だけでなく、「コード全体」を「テキストで」質問に貼り付けてください。

Comment: いつ答えが返ってくるかわからない掲示板で訊くより、先生に直接相談したほうが手早いです。よくわからないことを自認しているなら、そのことを先生に知ってもらうのも大事っス。

Comment: Colab だとテキストとしてコピペしづらいのは分かります。また今回の場合はスクリーンショットから現在のセルより上のセルが無いことが分かるので、スクリーンショットでも無茶苦茶駄目とは言いづらいところがありそうです。もちろんテキストにできるのであれば、問題を再現しやすくて回答しやすいので嬉しくはあります。

Answer (score 3):

以下のようなセルを用意し

```py
kingaku = int(input('金額'))
```

セルを実行 (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) を行い
(セル左側の再生ボタンのようなアイコン押したとか)

項目入力のプロンプトが表示されたところで

実行を中断 (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd>) を行ったのでしょう
(アニメーションしてるアイコンを押したか, キーボード操作を行ったのか, もしくはメニューから[ランタイム][実行を中断]を選択したのか, その辺りのはず)

こういう場合大抵は, エラーメッセージをよく読めば理由が書いてあります
(**ユーザーによる**インタラプト)

```
KeyboardInterrupt: Interrupted by user
```

対処？としては, 無視して操作続けて OKのはず

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。講義内では、コードを入れた際にすぐに左側にチェックマークが表示されエラーなど発生しなかったのですが、提示された練習問題からエラーが発生するようになりました。とりあえず、一通りコードを入れてみようと思います

Comment: すみません！解決しました！！！！数字を記入しなければならない場所に数字を入れたのですが、入れた後にEnterを入れ忘れていたみたいです！！！！お手数お掛けしました！！！！！